# Why importxml and importhtml not working here?

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

```
=Importhtml("https://app.neilpatel.com/en/ubersuggest/keyword_ideas?keyword=Food%20Chart&locId=2840&lang=en", "table", 3)
```

---

```
=ImportXML("https://app.neilpatel.com/en/ubersuggest/keyword_ideas?keyword=Food%20Chart&locId=2840&lang=en","//div[@class='css-19jz7zx']")
```

I use the above formula to get keywords in my google sheet. but I only get `#N/A`

> (Error
>   Imported content is empty)

I'm unable to understand what is wrong with my formula, why I'm unable to get data. please help me with this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that the reason of your issue is due to `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` which are shown when the value is retrieved from the URL with IMPORTXML and Google Apps Script.

For example, when the site is retrieved by the xpath of `//body`, only the value of `You need to enable JavaScript to run this app.` is returned.

[image]

Unfortunately, the built-in functions of Spreadsheet cannot be run the Javascript. By this, such error occurs. In this case, even when Google Apps Script was used, the values cannot be directly retrieved from the URL.