# How to scrape LinkedIn for connections with Google Sheets

Tags: xpath, web-scraping, google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

Trying to scrape my LinkedIn account for the first 20 connections using Google Sheets.

I'm guessing that it's not working because I'm asking for "mynetwork" but that doesn't give Google Sheets an id? Not sure, I'm brand new to Google Sheets.

Any help GREATLY appreciated!

**I've tried the following:**

---

```
=ImportFeed( "https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/")
```

> ERROR Imported Content is Empty

---

```
=IMPORTXML( "https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/", "//div[@class="ember-view")")
```

> ERROR Formula Parse Error

---

```
=IMPORTHTML("https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/", "list", "1")
```

> ERROR Could not fetch url: https://www.linkedin.com/mynetwork/invite-connect/connections/

---

Comment: Welcome. Google Sheets formulas can't import data from dynamic pages. Please take a look to [tag:google-sheets-importxml] i.e. [Why importxml and importhtml not working here?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58842048/1595451)

Comment: Thank you! Much Appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

The problem appears to be intermittent. The web query works whenever moved to a new sheet, or whenever the URL is broken and then corrected, forcing a refresh. The data is there one minute, and vanishes the next, but has always been restored as described.

The sheet is public at this [URL](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eo390FDVvWeNsnQ4Q7pBAWzKJ1-8QWGqMfchMsBm_7g/edit?usp=sharing), and te web query is present in the cell [AK12](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1Eo390FDVvWeNsnQ4Q7pBAWzKJ1-8QWGqMfchMsBm_7g/edit#gid=1107808919&range=AK12) at this writing. copy the sheet and then Break the URL and restore it to demonstrate the workaround.

Answer (score 0):

Google Sheets does not support scraping of JavaScript elements nor any elements behind the login. the best course of action would be to look at LinkedIn API: **https://developer.linkedin.com/docs/rest-api**