# Can't get NAV value using importXML

Tags: google-sheets-formula

I would like to have some help to get the NAV data from this link using importxml / xpath. https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/retail/ret/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8125/?prices ... so in this case the NAV data is $1.3446 . I would like to get this value using importxml / xpath.

How to do that? I've tried some formulas but.. not able to get the details from the website.

```
=(IMPORTXML("https://www.vanguardinvestments.com.au/retail/ret/investments/product.html#/fundDetail/wholesale/portId=8125/?prices","//td[@class='ng-binding']"))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that the issue in getting the value is that if you check the webpage source code [e.g. in Chrome `right click -> View Page Source`] that number is not directly available there

As outlined in [this other answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/61475850/4092588):

> IMPORTXML can not retrieve data which is populated by a script, and so
> using this formula to retrieve data from this table is not possible to
> do

This is why if you try to run it with its element xpath:

```
=IMPORTXML(A1,"//*[@id='tab-container']/div[2]/detail-prices-full/div/table[2]/tbody/tr[1]/td[2]")
```

you get empty content

The fact that the element is provided via a script can be confirmed by testing as suggested [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58846543/4092588), opening the developer tools of your browser and disabling JavaScript [e.g. [in Chrome](https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/javascript/disable)]

Without closing the developer tools, if you reload the website in this condition you'll see this:

[image: Website with JS disabled]

so you won't be able to get it via `IMPORTXML`